# xlwings representation of #N/A

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy, python-unittest, xlwings

I'm using xlwings with numpy and unittest in Python to test an Excel spreadsheet.  However, when xlwings is importing a value which has #N/A it is resulting in -2146826246.

I understand that this may have something to do with xlwings importing values as float, and there may not be a good float representation of #N/A.

I want to compare #N/A with nan.  Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who may stumble across the same problem in the future.  I used a very crude method of building a dictionary with the error numbers and the value which I wanted to return.

```
error_dict = {-2146826281:np.inf,-2146826246:np.nan}
```

If anyone has a more elegant solution, please let me know!

Comment: that helped a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another potential if you brought in (or converted) your excel data as a Pandas Dataframe you can always use replace to convert the old #N/A values to NaN's (which are a little easier to deal with in Python/Pandas..)

```
df.replace(-2146826246,float('nan'))
```

Answer (score 0):

When converting range to df, use this option

```
.options(empty=np.nan)
```

Then, treating like NaN different errors is very easy

```
df[df==-2146826246]=np.nan
```

This is very useful in order to avoid error while using functions and calculations to our data frame